# Android Developer Console - Device = Others

Tags: android

I have an app on the Android Market that I can see stats for on the Android Developer Console. The user base is 90% in the UK.

Under the Active Device Installs->Device tab 51% of the devices are "Other".

This seems pretty hopeless, could the missing devices be tablets ? Or is this info just not very accurate ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does anyone else have this issue ? I have now another 1000 users but still half are device "Others". Sounds like there are some very popular devices I am not seeing OR Google is not recording the installs properly.

Answer (score 5):

I contacted Google and found out you can get a full list of devices if you "Export to CSV" the statistics. Then you see all the different devices.

Beware there are a lot of different types of device with rather obscure names eg "m3" and "skate" !

Comment: Such a huge help, I was wondering why I had so many other countries and this helped figure that out quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try to integrate Google Analytics Mobile SDK into your app and use the Developer Console and Google Analytics together. GA can provide more accurate statistic results.

[Google Analytics Mobile SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/)

Comment: Actually that isn't quite what I want on consideration. Does anyone else have this issue ? I have now another 1000 users but still half are device "Others". Sounds like there are some very popular devices I am not seeing OR Google is not recording the installs properly.